# Custom Weighted CrossEntropy Loss not working as expeceted

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, conv-neural-network, multilabel-classification

I am trying to recreate the setup used in this [paper](https://openaccess.thecvf.com/content_cvpr_2017/papers/Wang_ChestX-ray8_Hospital-Scale_Chest_CVPR_2017_paper.pdf) on NIH Chest XRay Images Dataset.
I have tried to create the Custom LSE Global Pooling layer and Custom Loss Function Mentioned in the paper, but when I train the Model, it is having a hard time minimizing loss, the least it could achieve is 45, it gets stuck at that level.

I just need some help figuring out what I am doing wrong.
I have the code that I am using below:

### The Loss Function

```
def wcel(true,pred):
    pred = tf.clip_by_value(pred, 0.0000001, 1-0.0000001)
    no_pos = tf.reduce_sum(true,axis = 1)
    no_neg = tf.reduce_sum(1-true,axis = 1)
    bp = (no_pos+no_neg)/no_pos
    bn = (no_pos+no_neg)/no_neg
    loss = bp*tf.reduce_sum(tf.where(tf.equal(true,1),-tf.math.log(pred),0))+bn*tf.reduce_sum(tf.where(tf.equal(true,0),-tf.math.log(1-pred),0),axis = 1)
    return loss
```

[W-CEL defined in paper](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7jMqA.png)

### The LSE Layer

```
class GlobalLSEPooling2D(Layer):
    r = 0
    def __init__(self,r):
        super(GlobalLSEPooling2D,self).__init__()
        self.r = r
    def call(self,inputs):
        max_ele = tf.keras.backend.max(inputs, axis=[1,2],keepdims = True)
        rratio = 1/self.r
        S = (32*32)
        sratio = 1/S
        dif = inputs-max_ele
        r_prod = self.r*(dif)
        r_prod_exp = tf.math.exp(r_prod)
        s_exp = tf.reduce_sum(r_prod_exp,axis = [1,2],keepdims = True)
        sr_se_prod = sratio*s_exp
        lse = tf.math.add(rratio*tf.math.log((sr_se_prod)),max_ele)
        return(lse)
```

[LSE defined in Paper](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fHGzl.png)

### This is the model

```
def create_func_net():
    res50 = ResNet50(include_top = False,input_shape = (1024,1024,3))
    res101 = ResNet101(include_top = False,input_shape = (1024,1024,3))
    vgg16 = VGG16(include_top = False,input_shape = (1024,1024,3))
    vgg19 = VGG19(include_top = False,input_shape = (1024,1024,3))
    
    res50.trainable = False
    res101.trainable = False
    vgg19.trainable = False
    vgg16.trainable = False
    
    inputs = Input(shape = (1024,1024,1))
    to_3channels = Concatenate()([inputs,inputs,inputs])
    res50_out = res50(to_3channels)
    res101_out = res101(to_3channels)
    vgg16_out = vgg16(to_3channels)
    vgg19_out = vgg19(to_3channels)

    concat = Concatenate()([res50_out,res101_out,vgg16_out,vgg19_out])
    
    glob_pool = GlobalLSEPooling2D(10)(concat)
    
    flatten = Flatten()(glob_pool)
    
    prediction = Dense(units=(15),activation = 'sigmoid')(flatten)
    
    net = Model(inputs = [inputs], outputs = [prediction])
    
    net.compile(optimizer = optimizer,loss = BinaryCrossentropy(),metrics = ['accuracy',Recall(),Precision()])    
    return net
```

I have tried changing the learning rate it doesn't help much.
When I use Binary Crossentropy instead of the Custom Weighted Crossentropy, the optimization is much better but it does not predict well since its multilabel Classification.